# Flask - Trying to add an ID field in database which is incremented each time

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

This is the code from my models.py file. Everything was working until I tried to add a new field for "ID" which gets incremented with each item. This is a flask app running on google app engine.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
```

This is the traceback that I get:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute 'Column'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384688470778541604/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from blog import app
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384688470778541604/blog/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import views
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384688470778541604/blog/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models import Post
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384688470778541604/blog/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Post(db.Model):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~smart-cove-95709/1.384688470778541604/blog/models.py", line 4, in Post
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I also tried this without any success:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Integer(primary_key=True)
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Column` is not a member sine you're not using SQLAlchemy.

I think that Model from google.appengine.ext.db has some key out of the box, refer to google documentation

Comment: The other fields don't seem to use column and still work. Can I get away without using column? All I want is to add a unique ID to each entry

Comment: I see it's not SQLAlchemy you're using, since there's no 'Column' member.

Comment: It's GAE database. I still don't understand how to give each item a unique key :s

Comment: Answer is ```id = db.Integer()```

Comment: Good that you found it!